# AWS serverless - remove one resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

While using serverless I accidentally created two User Pools with the same name. One as a resource, and one because I forgot option `existing` while set upping Lambda trigger. Anyway, now I need to remove one of the already deployed User Pools.

So I want to exclude one of the Lambda functions with it's event from serverless stack and remove them. At least if I can remove resource from stack by it's arn it already will be great.

I don't want to remove all the stage and deploy it again. Even thought retain policy should save data from corruption, redeploying the whole project is clearly not the optimal solution...

```
functions:
  post_sign_up:
    ...
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: MyUserPool
          trigger: PostConfirmation
#          existing: true             ## The option I forgot :(
...
resources:
   UserPool:
      ...
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: MyUserPool
```